# Adding environment dependent parameters to the build

Tags: maven

In my company's parent POM I specify corporate repositories, that we all use. The URLs contain server name and the path of course. Each time I change the POM I publish a new version.

Now imagine, that the server hosting our repos gets renamed. I can change all URLs in the parent POM (not a problem) and publish a new version with fixed URLs. But I can't change URLs in the existing versions of the parent POM.

This means, that I can't rebuild any artifact from the past.

Is there some standard way to get around this problem? Like:

- Central property file
- A configuration POM with a fixed 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT version, that get republished on any change?

Answer (score 2):

You **never** put repositories except for distMngt in your POM. Again -- **never**. [You have burned your POMs forever.](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) This exists in Maven because repo managers did not exist back then. It is bad practice for years now and shall be removed.

Always use a Nexus instance with a repo group. This shall be added to your `settings.xml` which will mirror everything.

For those who don't believe, I am a long year Maven committer.

Comment: Ok, ok, I believe you :) But how about this: I have one repository for each JBoss version. Each project should use OLNY one (corresponding to JBoss version of the project). Also I would like to avoid updating all settings.xml's of all developers each time the new jboss version arrives.

Comment: @BorisBrodski That is a brain-dead approach. A repo can host as much versions as you like. Even if you go that route which I would not recommend, tell your Nexus admin to proxy those repos and add those proxies in a public group. Your devs won't even notice that. It will just work. At best, you create a route target for those repos in Nexus.

Comment: making all repos available to the project, makes it very easy to use a wrong version. I want to make sure, that only dependencies, that are later available through JBoss are used by the projects. Also adding new versions may break old builds, if version ranges are used (like, often in p2 repos)  Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Again -- I do not understand your approach!? Updating some versions means to run tests and then release it. There is no other way to make it reliable. *You* have full control over versions. It is not very easy to use the wrong version. This is a deliberate decision. While Eclipse/P2 make heavy use of version ranges -- it is discouraged with Maven because it can lead to build errors. Avoid it if you can.

You should elaborate your question. Maybe with snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If you use repositories in your parent pom and may change over time, the best strategy is in the URL or it use ALIAS (DNS, Apache redirect, Rewriting) and especially not the IP address directly , and you do not have to change the address of the repository every time.

Example:

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>myrepo</id>
          <url>http://myrepo.me/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
     </repositories>
```

and:

```
http://myrepo.me/content/repositories/public/ => ip address 1.2.3.4/*/*/
```

Comment: That is not the best strategy.

Comment: The company's DNS isn't cooperating :(. The only way I see here is to put alias into lmhosts of all developers PCs. But this isn't a nice solution, IMHO.

Comment: I consider that we can not touch the settings.xml

Comment: What can't you change you settings.xml file in your home folder `${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that we employ at work is to replace the URLs in the `<distributionManagement>` with parameters, like so:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>my-repo</id>
    <name>My Release Repo</name>
    <url>${url.deploy.releases}</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>my-repo</id>
    <name>My Release Repo</name>
    <url>${url.deploy.snapshots}</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

This way, we use `settings.xml` to control where the artifacts should be deployed. This has the advantage that if you ever migrate a repository (which we did) you only need to update `settings.xml` for new builds/releases.

If you need to go back to an earlier release and republish (for whatever reason) you just checkout the release tag, set up `settings.xml` to point to the new repo and do a `mvn clean deploy`.

If you can't modify `settings.xml` you can always just copy it, change the copy and point out the new settings file with the `-s` flag.

This approach also works for `<scm>` tags.

Comment: You commit your `settings.xml` with the project? (Otherwise you could just checkout an old tag and deploy it to the new URL.)

Comment: No, absolutely not. The settings file usually contains authentication credentials, which you do **not** want to put in your VCS. The approach you mentioned is not good practice. Suppose you checkout an old tag and change the settings file. If you commit, then the build isn't identical with the tag. If you don't commit, then then you have build you can't reproduce. One of Maven's tenets is to ensure that you have reproducible builds.

Comment: Ok, now I get you right. This is mostly the approach, I thought of. The sad thing is, that the `settings.xml` combines user and project preferences. I will try to use global and user `settings.xml` files to separate those concepts. I will provide the same global `settings.xml` with URLs to all users (probably through some shared network dir).